QR decomposition with increasingly large errors
I received a code to work on and it has a QR decomposition subroutine as shown below. When checking this QR decomposition using the error calculation I added at the end of it, I found the error increases to very high magnitudes after hundreds of simulation steps.
The QR decomposition is used to solve the coefficients used in triquadratic interpolation, adapted from trilinear interpolation as found on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation. In the code, we generate a 5x5x5 grid of values, and uses triquadratic interpolation to derive a spatial function form of the values to obtain f(x,y,z) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2y + a_3*z + ...
The function f(x,y,z) can be written as Ax = b for the pre-existing values on each grid point, such that b is the 125x1 vector of existing values, A is a 125x20 matrix calculated using the coordinates, and x is the 20x1 coefficient vector composed of (a_0, a_1, a_2, ...).
Then, x is calculated using the QR decomposition algorithm shown below. When I looked up QR decomposition, I found some discussions here that mentioned certain approaches can become increasingly unstable, but approaches such as householder reflection should be very stable.
My first question: I am having trouble identifying the type of approach used in my code, it doesn't normalize the variables and I can't match the process to other implementations found online. Can anyone tell me if this implementation is already a householder reflection?
My second question: If the implementation is correct and should be stable, can anyone give me some ideas to check why the solution would become increasingly unstable? Or if it is not householder or simply a bad implementation, would an example householder implementation that I found online help improve the accuracy?
  ! QR decomposition solving for vector B in AX = B
  subroutine qr_eqsystem(A, B, X, M, N, error)
  
  implicit none
  
  integer, intent(in) :: m, n
  real, intent(in) :: A(m, n), B(m)
  
  real, intent(out) :: x(n)
  real, intent(out) :: error
  
  !locals
  real :: q(m, n), r(n, n), aux
  integer :: i, j, k
  
  do i = 1,n
    do k = 1,m
      q(k, i) = A(k, i)
    enddo
  enddo
  
  do i = 1,n
    do j = 1,n
      r(j, i) = 0.0
    enddo
  enddo
  
  do i = 1,n
    do j = 1,i-1
      r(j, i) = 0.0
      do k = 1,m
        r(j, i) = r(j, i) + q(k, j)*A(k, i)
      enddo
      
      do k = 1,m
        q(k, i) = q(k, i) - r(j, i)*q(k,j)
      enddo
    enddo
    
    r(i, i) = 0.0
    do k = 1,m
      r(i, i) = r(i, i) + q(k, i)*q(k, i)
    enddo
    r(i, i) = sqrt(r(i, i))
    
    if(r(i,i).ne.0.0)then
      do k = 1,m
        q(k, i) = q(k, i) / r(i, i)
      enddo
    endif
    
  enddo
  
  do i = 1,n
    x(i) = 0.0
    do j = 1,m
      x(i) = x(i) + q(j, i)*B(j)
    enddo
  enddo
  
  if(r(n, n).ne.0.0)then
    x(n) = x(n) / r(n,n)
  endif
  
  do i = n-1,1,-1
    do j = i+1,n
      x(i) = x(i) - r(i, j) * x(j)
    enddo
    
    if(r(i, i).ne.0.0)then
       x(i) = x(i) / r(i, i)
    endif
  enddo
  
  error = 0
  
  ! calculate AX and compare with B as an error, report total raw error
  do i = 1,m
    aux = 0.0
    do j = 1,n
      aux = aux + A(i,j)*X(j)
    enddo
    error = error + abs(aux - B(i))
  enddo
  
  endsubroutine qr_eqsystem


Unless real in your choice of language is actually 64 bit double precision FP the first thing to try is increasing the precision of the array and working variables to at least double and if your language allows it x87 80 bit floating point reals. BTW You would probably be better off fitting Chebyshev polynomials rather than x^n, y^n, z^n. I think your problems may stem from that ill posed nature of the question being asked of the matrix equation solver rather than the solver itself. Easy way to test is find another solver that is pin compatible and give it a whirl.

@MartinBrown thanks Martin, real is compiled as double precision so it shouldn't be a precision-related issue. Per the comment on fitting Chebyshev polynomials, are you referring to the triquadratic interpolation approach that uses x^n type polynomials, and suggest using sines and cosines?

Rescale each variable range onto -1,1 for x,y,z and then use cos(n.acos(x)) instead of x^n. The resulting fitting matrix will be much better conditioned. I have never actually done it for multiple variables but it works very well on otherwise difficult functions in 1D. You can convert back to polynomial form afterwards if that is what you need.

"real is compiled as double precision" If you are using compiler flags to change the type of  variables you are asking for a world of pain. Please show us exactly how you compiled the code. Also why aren't you using LAPACK?

I'm not awake properly yet, but the above looks like a Gram-Schmidt approach, which is definitely one of the numerically unstable approaches. I strongly suggest you use LAPACK. Nobody should have been writing dense linear algebra routines for the last quarter of a century+.

To say much more than that we need a minimal, reproducible example

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65112046/householder-qr-factorization-using-lapack-and-fortran/65122852#65122852 might be of interest

You may be using something like this already but in case you haven't seen it before this is quite a good trick to improve the condition of the matrix even if you stick with x^n. Choosing the right values of x can make a helpful difference for interpolating polynomials.

@IanBush thank you Ian for the insights. I will look into using LAPACK but it can be very tricky with the Fortran code that I am using. The code was originally developed in 1993 and worked on by many many researchers since then. It is just compiled with the flags "real-size:64" and "Qsave". My most probable approach is to find a householder reflection implementation and add it to the code instead.

@IanBush I read through the LAPACK installation page (I searched "LAPACK for windows") and I have some questions on installing LAPACK on Windows, could you help me with it? Maybe we should move to DMs

Sorry! I don't use Windows at all

@IanBush no problem, you have been big help already. Just one question then: Do I need all of BLAS, LAPACK, and LAPACKE?

If you guys want to leave an answer below, I will accept it.

Your QR decomposition implementation looks normal (far from ideal, but normal). You can compare the absolute values of the diagonal R with the LAPACK implementation or with Python numpy.linalg.qr().
However, numerical stability of the solution only means that
|x - x'|/|x| <= f(m, n)*cond(A)*eps
where, f(m, n) is a function of a small degree from m and n, cond(A) is a condition number approximately equal to the ratio of the maximum and minimum absolute values diagonal of the matrix R (A ≈ QR).
However, the magnitude of the residual of the solution of the least squares system Ax = B may still be significant for two reasons:

The system is incompatible;
The number of conditionality (cond(A)) is too high.

I think it's worth looking for computational errors in calculating the matrix A and the right parts of B.

I think you are right that the problem is at least in part due to how the matrix A has been computed and refinements to that side of the problem might pay dividends. Fitting polynomials directly results in a very ill conditioned matrix problem. The OP might also want to try a compiler that allows native x87 precision or even quad precision for his matrix solver - that would greatly reduce numerical error in the solver for a minor code change real -> real10 or real16.  ISTR Silverfrost (formerly Salford) and GNU both have that option. Is the code trying to find an equal ripple polynomial?

@MartinBrown hi Martin, I started a new question as my issue has changed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78721961/qr-decomposition-successful-but-has-high-errors I checked the decomposed Q and R matrices and it turns out the decomposition itself isn't an issue, but somehow the back substitution solved x in Ax=B produces a large error when evaluating Ax - B

Hi Serge, please see the above comment for the link of the new question with more information. Both of your proposed causes, incompatible system and conditionality, affect the QR decomposition process itself, is that correct? My new question described that I checked Q and R are both reasonable.
